# Multi-dimensional associative array with named index

Tags: javascript

Spent quite some time and googled but I can't seem to achieve this in Javascript:

PHP:

```
$items['01A']['price'] = "$30";
$items['01A']['description'] = "Description1";

$items['02B']['price'] = "$60";
$items['02B']['description'] = "Description2";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [01A] => Array
        (
            [price] => $30
            [description] => Description1
        )

    [02B] => Array
        (
            [price] => $60
            [description] => Description2
        )

)
```

Well, I can, like so:

```
var obj = {
    '0113A5' : {
        'price' : '1200',
        'discount' : '5'
    },
    '0213A5' : {
        'price' : '1800',
        'discount' : '0'
    }
};
```

... but assigning values inside a look isn't possible because this:

```
obj['0313A5']['price'] = "2000";
//or
obj.0313A5.price = "2000";
```

... throws an error.

Comment: `obj['0313A5']['price'] = "2000";` is perfectly valid... what's the error you see?

Comment: @gp. `TypeError: Cannot set property 'price' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create empty object before assign properties to it, like this

```
var obj = {};

obj['0113A5'] = {};
obj['0113A5'].price = '1200';
obj['0113A5'].discount = '5';


obj['0213A5'] = {};
obj['0213A5'].price = '1800';
obj['0213A5'].discount = '0';
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/tasiyu/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
            '0113A5' : {
                'price' : '1200',
                'discount' : '5'
            },
            '0213A5' : {
                'price' : '1800',
                'discount' : '0'
            }
        };

obj['0113A5']['discount'] = '222';
alert(obj['0113A5']['discount']);

obj['0113A5'].discount = '333';
alert(obj['0113A5']['discount']);
```

It is valid.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jq5esg2/